# what is default qemu arm enviroment in qemu-arm-static?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I tried qemu-arm-static in Ubuntu.

In QEMU system, I type below for execution.

```
# qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu ....
```

It means that we give the configuration(like versatilepb) to QEMU.

Now, I install qemu-user-static.
Then I execute qemu-arm-static using chroot.

In that case, we don't give any configuration..

what is the default configuration in qemu-arm-staic??

I mean something like board name, cpu name ...
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `qemu-arm-static` translates ARM machine instructions into your host cpu machine instructions. There is no layer of `-M` or `-machine` virtualization. There is no layer of virtualizing the PCI devices, SCSI devices, hard drives, motherboard, RAM size and like CPU speed. These do not exists, cause the machine the `qemu-arm-static` is running on is your host machine and `qemu-arm-static` just translates one machine instructions into another set.

I don't know how do you get the "board name" on your host machine, but if you run `dmidecode -t 2` on `qemu-arm-static` i guess it should return your host "board name" (if it works). The "cpu name" will be the same, as syscalls are transferred to running kernel and querying for the "cpu name" from /proc/cpuinfo will be the same as on your host.

> It means that we give the configuration(like versatilepb) to QEMU.

`versatilepb` is the virtualization of the [`Arm926EJ-S`](https://www.nxp.com/products/no-longer-manufactured/arm926ej-s-with-256-kb-sram-usb-high-speed-otg-sd-mmc-nand-flash-controller-lcd-controller:LPC3230FET296) board. It has 32 kB instruction cache and a 32 kB data cache
and 256 kB of Internal SRAM and so on. `qemu-arm-static` uses your host RAM and your host cpu speed - it does not virtualizes RAM accesses and similar. So there is no such configuration in `qemu-arm-static`.

> In that case, we don't give any configuration...

The `-cpu` in `qemu-arm-static` default to `any`, ie. it understands all machine instructions sets available for arm platform it was written to support. That is at least all of the 32-bit Thumb/Thumb-2 instruction sets.

> what is the default configuration in `qemu-arm-static`??

The relevant option to this question is `-cpu any`.